# Python regex match whole string only

Tags: python, regex

Is there any easy way to test whether a regex matches an entire string in Python? I thought that putting `$` at the end would do this, but it turns out that `$` doesn't work in the case of trailing newlines.

For example, the following returns a match, even though that's not what I want.

```
re.match(r'\w+$', 'foo\n')
```

Comment: The defacto standard is `\A<your regex>\z` Supercedes all modes, etc..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `\Z`:

**`\Z`**

> Matches only at the end of the string.

```
In [5]: re.match(r'\w+\Z', 'foo\n')

In [6]: re.match(r'\w+\Z', 'foo')
Out[6]: <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 3), match='foo'>
```

Comment: Arguably a better answer than mine, since this is what `\Z` is *for*.

Comment: You've started to test my patience https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax

Comment: @BhargavRao, there is no direct link to the `\Z` so I just stole  the line from the docs,  what's in my answer is pretty much it.

Comment: Argh, you don't need direct link. It comes under the expression syntax. So you can add the link and mention that it is at the end. :P

Comment: @BhargavRao, sending someone to look for  *Matches only at the end of the string.*  feels wrong!

Comment: Lol.. Also it is actually ironical that `\z` is at the end of the section . *Please look at the end of the list to see what matches only at the end of the string*

Comment: @BhargavRao, I think that may well be the least stimulating  piece of documentation in the world!

Answer (score 5):

To test whether you matched the entire string, just check if the matched string is as long as the entire string:

```
m = re.match(r".*", mystring)
start, stop = m.span()
if stop-start == len(mystring):
    print("The entire string matched")
```

Note: This is independent of the question (which you didn't ask) of how to match a trailing newline.

Comment: I think there is an error in the code. I guess `len(mystring)`  is enough. Subtracting `-1` seems not to  be correct

Answer (score 3):

You can use a negative lookahead assertion to require that the `$` is not followed by a trailing newline:

```
>>> re.match(r'\w+$(?!\n)', 'foo\n')
>>> re.match(r'\w+$(?!\n)', 'foo')
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 3), match='foo'>
```

`re.MULTILINE` is not relevant here; OP has it turned off and the regex is still matching.  The problem is that `$` *always* matches [right before the trailing newline](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.M):

> When [`re.MULTILINE` is] specified, the pattern character `'^'` matches at the beginning of the string and at the beginning of each line (immediately following each newline); and the pattern character `'$'` matches at the end of the string and at the end of each line (immediately preceding each newline). By default, `'^'` matches only at the beginning of the string, and `'$'` only at the end of the string and **immediately before the newline (if any) at the end of the string.**

I have experimentally verified that this works correctly with [`re.X`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.X) enabled.

Comment: Yup, deleted my answer. Misunderstood the OP's goal.

Answer (score 2):

Based on @alexis answer:
A method to check for a fullMatch could look like this:

```
def fullMatch(matchObject, fullString):
    if matchObject is None:
        return False
    start, stop = matchObject.span()
    return stop-start == len(fullString):
```

Where the `fullString` is the String on which you apply the regex and the `matchObject` is the result of `matchObject = re.match(yourRegex, fullString)`